# Converting byte[] containing multiple encodings into String using StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, byte

I have a byte[] array that contains data I want to convert to a String.  I am currently simply using a StringBuilder and casting byte to char using the following code:

```
String getAscii(int offset, int count) {
    sbAscii.setLength(0);

    for (getAsciiCounter = 0; getAsciiCounter < count; getAsciiCounter++) {
        sbAscii.append((char) bytes[offset + getAsciiCounter]);
    }

    return sbAscii.toString();
}
```

Everything is working as expected, until my bytes contain something similar to "Nick\xe2\x80\x99s Stuff".  My question to the experts is: how can I modify my method so sbAscii.toString() returns "Nick's Stuff" instead of "Nick(strange symbols)s Stuff"?  Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `String` constructor that accepts a `byte[]` and a charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) String method

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] 
            { 78, 105, 99, 107, 39, 115, 32, 83, 116, 117, 102, 102 };
String value = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
```

Or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29) method

```
String value = new String(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: The second method did the trick splendidly.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to do `new String(bytes,offset,count)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import  java.nio.charset.Charset;

...

public String convertFromASCII(byte[] strBuf, int offset, int count)
{
    Charset asciiCharset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
    return new String(strBuf, offset, count, asciiCharset);
}
```